# If $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ and $a_0+\frac{a_1}2+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$ show that there exists an x with $0\lt x \lt 1$ and $P(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a problem in my Math Analysis class, in which we are studying derivatives and other basic calculus functions. We have covered up until L'Hopital's rule, and I do not even know where to begin with this problem. I think that the answer has to do with big O notation, but I'm not entirely sure how that works. In class, we performed a similar exercise to prove that the derivative of $e^x$ equals $e^x$, but I'm not sure how to apply that to this problem. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Yeah, the major problem is that $a_{0} + \cdots + \frac{a_{n}}{n+1}$ should be followed by some relation (say $=$).

Comment: @Kevin McDonough If I remembered correctly, this is an exercise from Rudin's book, I will try to edit, let me know if it is not.

Comment: I fixed it according to the book, thank you for the heads-up!

Comment: I am using Browder's book "Mathematical Analysis: An Introduction"

Comment: You can begin with a question by S.Panja-1729, asked less than an hour ago.That question is more complicated, but you will find the answer to your question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = a_0 x + \frac{a_1}{2} x^2 + \cdots + \frac{a_{n - 1}}{n} x^n + \frac{a_n}{n + 1} x^{n + 1}, \; x \in [0, 1]$. Clearly, $f$ is differentiable on $[0, 1]$. In addition, $f(0) = 0$, and by condition, $f(1) = 0$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $y \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$f(1) - f(0) = 0 = f'(y) (1 - 0) = f'(y).$$
Since $f'(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + a_n x^n = P(x)$, the result follows.

Comment: Your answer seems pretty much correct, do you have any tips for how I could notice this on a test or quiz?

Comment: Understand the theorem, connect the pattern of the condition and goal, and most importantly, do more exercises, which will sharp your agility.